# $stateProvider not loading pages as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am trying to use `$stateProvider` for my url routing. I thought that if I use `$stateProvider`, then I don't need to use `$routeProvider`. Is this correct? I was able to get my url routing to work with `$routeProvider`, but am unable to get my url routing to work with `$stateProvider`. Here is the code I have so far:

```
var app = angular.module("app",['ui.state']);
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home") 

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        views: {
            main: { templateUrl: "views/home/main.html" }
            sub: { templateUrl: "views/home/sub.html" }
        }
    })
    .state('products/info', {
        url: "/products/info",
        controller: 'ProductsCtrl',
        views: {
            main: { templateUrl: "views/products/main.html" },
            sub: { templateUrl: "views/products/info/sub.html" } 
        }
    })
    .state('products/reviews', {
        url: "/products/reviews",
        controller: 'ProductsCtrl',
        views: {
            sub: { templateUrl: "views/products/reviews/sub.html" } 
        }
    })
```

On my "shell" html page I have the following:

```
<div class="main">
    <div ui-view="main"></div>
    <div ui-view="sub"></div>
</div>
```

When I visit any of my urls I only see the shell html page. Nothing is being loaded into my `ui-view`'s. What am I missing?

Comment: Nothing in the console?

Comment: Nothing is listed in the console when I try to visit my urls.

Comment: Okay breakpoints hitting in the config call?  Also how bout in the controllers.

Answer (score 2):

here,your state type 'products/reviews' is wrong,it should be 'products.reviews'

Answer (score 1):

This page explained it: [AngularJS State Management with ui-router](http://txt.fliglio.com/2013/05/angularjs-state-management-with-ui-router/)

Answer (score 1):

The dependency name is 'ui.router' not 'ui.state'