# $stateProvider not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Before I start, I have looked around many other answers:

- [$stateProvider not loading pages as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661415/stateprovider-not-loading-pages-as-expected)
- [angular $stateProvider not routing as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813103/angular-stateprovider-not-routing-as-expected)
- [angular $stateprovider not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802226/angular-stateprovider-not-working-as-expected)
- [AngularJS stateProvider not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593132/angularjs-stateprovider-not-working)

I am building an app with Ionic.
I have created the app from another one I am working on, however, the `$stateProvider` seems to be working on that one and not this. The only difference being that the working one was set up as an Ionic tabs (`ionic start myApp tabs`) template and this one was setup as a blank template (`ionic start myApp blank`). The `index.html` is loading as expected but when I visit `/login`, the HTML page is not loading, nor the controller with it.

**routes.js**

```
angular.module('vCAFI.routes', [])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('blocklyEditor', {
        url: '/blocklyEditor',
        templateUrl: 'templates/blocklyEditor.html',
        controller: 'blocklyEditorCtrl'
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login')
});
```

**login.html**

```
<ion-view title="Login" hide-nav-bar="true" hide-back-button="true" cache-view="false" nav-transition="none" id="page2">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="manual-ios-statusbar-padding" scroll="false">

    ...

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

There is not a `ui-view` directive or anything as Angular substitutes it for `ion-view`.

When I visit:

> localhost:8100/#/login

...I am returned with `index.html`. When I hit:

> localhost:8100/templates/login.html

...the it can find the correct page *(but with no Ionic stuff loaded in as `index.html` has not been loaded in yet)*

I have played around setting `templateUrl` to different paths to `login.html` but nothing works.

There is no `ui.router` or `ui.state` injected into the app as I am told that Ionic doesn't require it. I have tested it with those dependencies as well but still no look.

Finally, there is nothing in the log when debugging and - when putting a breakpoint in - `routes.js` is being hit which means it's being loaded in correctly.

I have added a `$stateChangeError` handler but still not output to the log:

```
.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
})
```

*(I've never implemented this handler before so correct me if I am wrong)*

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: add a state change error handler and log any errors it produces

Comment: There is nothing being produced in the log

Comment: That's not overly informative. Is error handler triggered? If so show the handler code

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: @charlietfl the way I have implemented it, it's not being triggered

Comment: Ok...well that appears to be set up correctly. I don't work with ionic much are you sure that a `<ui-view>` is not needed? try putting one in and see what happens. Also is the correct url being maintained when you try changing routes?

Comment: @charlietfl referencing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444602/using-ui-router-in-the-ionic-framework-in-angularjs#23495006 and with the last project I am using as a template, it's not needed

Comment: Create a demo in plunker or codepen that reproduces this

Comment: Note that the linked answer demo has an `<ion-nav-view>` which you don't seem to have

Comment: That was the error. Ionic looks for `<ion-nav-view>` instead of `<ui-view>`. If you put it as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `<ion-nav-view>` element for the route templates to render in